# How do I give GPIO and USB permissions to a k3s Kubernetes pod?

Tags: gpio, pi-4, virtualization

I am trying to run Home Assistant from my Raspberry Pi 4 using K3s Kubernetes. I can get it up and running but now I want to give it access to my GPIO. What is the proper way to give those permissions to the pod running the application?

Comment: You may need to play with sysfs as per the rather similar discussion I had here
https://github.com/openfaas/faas/issues/1238#issuecomment-1212913881

Answer (score 1):

this works by giving the container full privileges

If you have the usb on a dedicated Raspberry Pi you have to label this node first via

```
kubectl label nodes <node-name> device=myraspi
```

and then use a node selector to assure that this pod runs on the Pi
A Pod definition would look like this

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
  name: home-assistant
spec:
  nodeSelector:
    device: myraspi
  containers:
    - image: <image-name>
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      name: led-blue
      securityContext:
        privileged: true
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).